# How to find a good writing partner

Tags: criticism

I find I write much better, more often, etc. when I have someone else who is also writing, and we can share ideas, bits of writing, even larger parts of manuscripts. What's the best place to go to find individuals who are also interested in doing this?
I'm not going to be able to find anyone local, I live in a small town, so I'm looking for someone(s) I can connect with online.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest [NaNoWriMo](https://nanowrimo.org/)? Apart from the eponymous writing challenge, which takes place every November, the site allows you to join groups of other writers for online discussions, find other writers in your area (though you mentioned that's not an option for you), and also has [its own forum](https://forums.nanowrimo.org/). I presume these facilities are active and available all year round, though they will be less active outside of NaNoWriMo itself.

The site also runs Camp NaNoWriMo, a more relaxed writing challenge that takes place every April and July - in other words, there's a Camp NaNoWriMo event going on as I type this.

Anecdotally, I'm in a Facebook group with a bunch of NaNoWriMo users in my own area (Essex, UK), and when I competed in NaNoWriMo in 2017, I found it very useful for gauging my progress and motivating myself to keep going.